# Extremely slow ethernet connection after fresh install of 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet

At first, upon installing ubuntu 16.04 on my work computer (Dell Studio XPS 9100), I had no connection to the internet at all (previously it was very fast over Windows 10). I fixed this by setting up a static IP.

To do so, I first modified `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and changed:

`#dns=dnsmasq (comment out the dnsmasq)
[ifupdown]
managed=true (changed from false)`

I then used the command `sudo gedit /etc/network/interface` and added:

`iface enp2s0 inet static
address 130.63.110.83
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 130.63.110.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`

However, while I was able to get a connection after this fix, it was extremely slow. To do so, I attempted the following fixes:

Attempt to force the computer to prefer IPV6 over IPV4:

`sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf`

Added these configurations at the end of file:

`# IPv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1`

Then restarted `sysctl.conf`:

`$ sudo sysctl -p`

I also tried to execute the line `sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6 <<<"1"`

And additionally to modify `/etc/nsswitch.conf` by changing `hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4` to `hosts: files dns`

The last fix I have attempted was to open `/etc/gai.conf` and uncomment `#precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100`

I restarted after every fix, but none of them had any noticeable effect on improving internet speeds, which were still abysmal compared to the speeds available through the windows 10 OS.

This is the output I get when I run ifconfig:

`enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ac:6f:ff:e2:fe

          inet addr:130.63.110.81  Bcast:130.63.110.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::10fa:b4dc:3b4a:22fd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:176482 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:23839 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:129782184 (129.7 MB)  TX bytes:2439348 (2.4 MB)`

`lo        Link encap:Local Loopback

          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:171 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:171 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12577 (12.5 KB)  TX bytes:12577 (12.5 KB)`

Answer (score 0):

Was the address x.83 given to you by the network administrator? We notice that `ifconfig` shows x.81, and we suspect that there are conflicting settings in Network Manager.

I think you actually want `managed=false` which means that Network Manager will *NOT* manage any interfaces declared in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Please revert the file. You probably also want to add: `auto enp2s0`.

Next, restart NM:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Down and up the interface to get the system to read and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown enp2s0 && sudo ifup -v enp2s0
```

Did you get the correct address?

```
ifconfig
```

Any improvement?

Comment: I got the address from the network administrator, yeah. I'm getting the error Unknown interface enp2s0

Comment: After making the changes I suggested, please try a reboot.

Comment: I still getunknown interface enp2s0 when I try to run `sudo ifdown enp2s0 && sudo ifup -v enp2s0`

Comment: Additionally, I am no longer able to connect to any website when I make the suggested changes

Comment: What does this report as the interface? `ifconfig` Also, are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep enp`